# Fetch post method from js to PHP script (API)

Tags: javascript, php, post, fetch-api

I am new to this part of communication between client site and server.
My client is js who fetch object to PHP script called server.php.

registration.js

```
let json = {
    name: name,
    date: date,
    phone: phone,
};

     const options = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(json),
        };
        fetch(
            `http://localhost/php/server.php/registration`,
            options
        );
```

How do I know if request is a registration request or something else?

If I create in server.php script:

```
 if (isset($_POST'['registration']) { ... }
```

PHP says that is not set `$_POST'['registration'];`

Comment: you can `print_r($_POST);` to read what's inside, and find an appropriate value to check against the word "registration"

Comment: @GrafiCode — No, they can't. There's nothing inside `$_POST`.

Comment: `if (isset($_POST'['registration'])` should show a "Parse error"

Comment: use ajax post method. use simple JQuery library.

Comment: @NaveenRoy — Why? Adding jQuery would be **more complicated** then the approach the OP is taking. (Not to mention the bloat added to the page. jQuery is massive.)

Comment: check documentation here   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` contains data that is:

- In the request body
- Encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`

Your request body is encoded as `application/json` so `$_POST` will be blank, and `registration` appears in the URL, not the request body anyway.

Look to [`$_SERVER[PATH_INFO]`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) instead.

> Contains any client-provided pathname information trailing the actual
> script filename but preceding the query string, if available. For
> instance, if the current script was accessed via the URL
> http://www.example.com/php/path_info.php/some/stuff?foo=bar, then
> $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] would contain /some/stuff.